# Gnome-flashback "Applications" menu disappeared

Tags: gnome, gnome-flashback

I don't remember the *exact* circumstances when it happened, I think I installed or updated some packages..
Thing is - my Gnome's (I'm using flashback) "Applications" menu became empty. Everything else works just fine, but there is neither folders, nor applications in the menu.
Is there a way to generate it again somehow since all the *.desktop files in /usr/share/applications are there untouched?